# Python piping to `gzip.open` filehandle

Tags: python, gzip

The following code snippet opens a gzip file handle and writes a line to it, then it opens it again in append mode and redirects the stdout of a subprocess to the gzipped file handle.

```
import gzip
import subprocess

with gzip.open("./file.txt.gz", "w") as fh:
    fh.write("this is the first line\n")

with gzip.open("./file.txt.gz", "a") as fh:
    subprocess.call("echo this is the second line", shell=True, stdout=fh)
```

When I attempt to decompress the file to see what I have written to it, I get the following error

```
$ gunzip file.txt.gz
gzip: file.txt.gz: decompression OK, trailing garbage ignored
```

The decompressed contents consist solely of the first line

```
$ cat file.txt
this is the first line
```

When I use the same file handle for writing a line and as the output of a process, I get a file that isn't even recognized by `gunzip`.

```
import gzip
import subprocess

with gzip.open("./file.txt.gz", "w") as fh:
    fh.write("this is the first line\n")
    subprocess.call("echo this is the second line", shell=True, stdout=fh)
```

For instance, produces a file that cannot be `gunzip`'d.

```
$ gunzip file.txt.gz

gzip: file.txt.gz: not in gzip format
```

Is there a way of passing a gzip-flavored pseudo-filehandle to a process run via `subprocess` or is there really no alternative to writing the file non-compressed and then going back and compressing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search StackOverflow, you'll find this issue comes up occasionally but the answers aren't always straightforward to implement.  The gist of them seems to be that `subprocess.call()` can't pass a pseudo-filehandle -- it has to be the real thing.  The standard workaround seems to be using `subprocess.Popen()`.

However, here's a simple compromise I worked out:

```
import gzip
import subprocess

with gzip.open("file.txt.gz", "wt") as handle:
    handle.write("this is the first line\n")

completed = subprocess.run("echo 'this is the second line'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

with gzip.open("file.txt.gz", "at") as handle:
    handle.write(completed.stdout)
```

The idea is to delay appending the compressed data until after the subprocess completes:

```
> gzcat file.txt.gz
this is the first line
this is the second line
>
```

The `subprocess.run()` function was added in Python 3.5